# Remove bins/ stat_bin2d/ set lower bound for number of objects in bin for display

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the command

```
stat_bin2d(bins=150, aes(fill=cut(..count.., c(10,20,50,100,200,Inf))))
```

In my code because I wish to count objects in certain geographic locations. I do not want to display bins on my plot that have fewer than 10 objects.

Above code only results in bins with fewer than 10 objects being shaded grey.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a limit of 10, any values less than 10 are treated as `NA`, ie. missing values. You can manually change the colour of NA's via

```
+ scale_fill_hue(na.value="white")
```

If you don't want anything plotted, you could make the point completely transparent (`alpha=0`)

```
## This seems a hack, but works
+ scale_fill_hue(na.value=rgb(0, 0, 0, alpha=0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Admittedly to add your line above, I had to comment out scale_fill_grey("Number of Voters", start=0.9, end=0.38, labels=c("<200","200-500","500-1000","1000-2000",">2000")).  Firstly, is there any way to combine these two lines of code?  Secondly, are you sure that any bins with fewer than 10 counts will be treated as NA?  Is there a way I can check this?

Comment: Use `scale_fill_grey(na.value="a_colour", .....)` To check, change `a_colour` to an easy to spot colour

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better plan than just trying to blend in to the background:

`+ scale_fill_whatever(..., limits = c(10, NA), na.value = NA)`